# Linq one list to select multiple items from another list

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have three classes as below:

```
public class Product
{
    int id { get; set; }
    int creationDate { get; set; }
}
public class ProductList
{
    List<Product> productsList;
}
```

And

```
public class SelectedId
{
    List<int> selectedIds;
}
```

Now I have 2 lists:

1. selectedIds
2. products

   I want to get each `Product` from `productsList` whose `Id` is equal to the values in `selectedId` in the sequence of `Ids` mentioned in `selectedIds`.

Presently I am doing something like this:

```
foreach (var sID in selectedId)
{
   var product = productsList.First(x => x.id == sID);
   products.Add(product);
}
```

Please suggest a better way to do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try IEnumerable extension method [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Join__4_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Func___0___2__System_Func___1___2__System_Func___0___1___3__)

```
var result = products.Join(selectedIds, p => p.id, i => i, (p, i) => p).ToList()
```

Comment: This is imho the way to do it. But if you find yourself doing this a lot, it might actually be better to have a Dictionary<int, Product> instead of the `productList`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) and [`.Contains()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains), as follows:

```
var newList = productsList.Where(p => selectedIds.Contains(p.id)).ToList();
```

In plain text this means "get all items from `productsList` for which the id occurs in `selectedIds`".

*Note* - if there are duplicate values in `selectedIds`, these will be "distincted" away because we only return each Product at most once. If there are duplicates and you do care about also having duplicate Products as a result (+ in the same order as all the ids), then use a form such as this:

```
var newList = selectedIds.Select(id => productsList.First(p => p.id == id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like that

```
var productsList =productsList.Where((product) =>  selectedId.Any((id) => id == product.Id));
```

The Szymon's solution seems better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this, here's one:

```
var selected = productsList.Where(p => selectedIds.Contains(p.id))
```

You can use `Any` instead of `Contains`.

If you are adding `selected` to another collection of products you can use `anotherCollection.AddRange`.

Answer (score 0):

Can try a linq query with joint:

```
    var query = from id in selectedId
                       join product in productsList on id.selectedIds equals product.id
                       select new { id  = id.id , creationDate  = product.creationDate  };
```